Should Firestore snapshot listeners be automatically removed when a View is dismissed?
I’ve noticed that Firestore doesn’t automatically remove snapshot listeners when a view is dismissed.
For example, in my Login view, I fetch a list of accounts using a Firestore snapshot listener and pass a completion handler to it. After logging in, when I navigate to the Home view and add a new account, the completion handler from the Login view still gets triggered.
I know that we can manually remove the snapshot listener, but shouldn’t Firestore automatically remove the snapshot listener when the Login view disappears? Why isn’t this happening?
Additionally, in the Login view, I have a state variable storing some data, and I tried printing it inside the completion handler. I can see that it still holds the data, even though the Login view should have been deallocated.
Why does this listener persist beyond the view’s lifecycle?

No you have to remove them but there is FirestoreQuery as an alternative or you can wrap the listener in an AsyncStream and include the removal when the rain terminates

Not all listeners need to be tied to a view lifecycle - you have to determine if that's the case, then implement it properly.  For example, you might want to capture updates to a document immediately in the "background" of your app, no matter what the user is doing or looking at.  Or, maybe a listener needs to be active through several views so that you don't unnecessarily query the database on each one.
It's up to you, the programmer, to determine the right time to remove a listener for your particular use case.  If the right times are tied to a view lifecycle, then that's the code you should write.  The Firebase SDK can't know what you want ahead of time.

When you need to read data in real time from Firestore, you have to attach a persistence listener. This means that if you want to no longer listen to real-time updates, then you have to explicitly detach the listener so that your event callbacks stop getting called. This is necessary because allows your client to stop using the bandwidth. Less bandwidth, less to pay. In Swift it should look like this:
let listener = query.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
  //Get data and handle errors.
}

// ...

// Remove listener to stop listening to changes
listener.remove() //

Also remember, a listener isn't tied in any way to a View. You have to detach it as soon as you that the listener is no longer needed.

I know we can remove it manually, but if Firestore doesn't remove it automatically when a view is dismissed, and the user forgets to do so, it could lead to several issues such as unnecessary requests, completion handlers performing unnecessary tasks, or even incorrect data if there are calculations inside the completion handler.

Yes, that's exactly what happens if you forget to remove a listener. So you should always take into consideration, removing all listeners as soon as they are no longer needed.

Hi @Alex Mamo, as I mentioned, I know how to remove the listener manually and I understand the consequences of not doing so. The point is that with this design, it can cause potential issues for new users who may not have much experience with Firestore, especially since the listener will not be overridden but will instead create new instances and keep the old ones.

Yes, you're entirely correct. That's why new users should pay more attention to the details of implementing such mechanisms. That's almost the same thing as implementing Firestore Security Rules. If you ignore them, anybody who knows your project ID will be able to read/write to/from your database. Which is obviously bad, since malicious users can take advantage of it. So always read the official documentation carefully!

So did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?

The answer doesn't relate to my question. I know how to remove the listener. My expectation is that Firestore should provide a clear way for users to have better control over the listener, such as automatically removing it when the screen turns off or overriding the old listener when reassigned to the same completion handler. This would prevent potential issues.

What I wrote, indeed answers your question. The fact that your expectations are different than how things work, is something that frequently happens in software development. However, remember that iOS views are not tied to Firebase listeners, and it makes sense to behave that way because other developers might not understand why a listener is removed automatically instead of continuing to listen. When you're in charge, it's up to you to decide when and how to remove them.

If you think that the actual mechanisms aren't working in a proper way, then I recommend you reach out to Firebase Support or add a suggestion on firebase.uservoice.com.
